# Visual Studio 2012 with .NET Framework 4

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.0, frameworks, visual-studio-2012

If I'm still writing majority of my apps in .NET Framework 4, mostly because I still need to support WinXP, is it recommended to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012? Or would it be of negligible benefit?

I have read a lot of articles that talk about the improvements about VS2012 coupled with .NET Framework 4.5, but what about 4.0?

Any real reason to jump to VS2012 if I'm still writing a lot of .NET 4.0 apps/web apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [improvements to web application development](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/05/31/new-features-for-web-development-in-visual-studio-2012-rc.aspx), but whether they constitute a "real reason" is really up to you. For desktop applications targeted to .NET 4 there's probably nothing that would justify the cost of the switch; you can browse the [list of changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx) to reach your own conclusion.